# XPath - how to count() & group by each element value?

Tags: xml, xpath, aggregate, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

Sample XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<names>
  <name>abc</name>
  <name>abc</name>
  <name>xyz</name>
  <name>def</name>
  <name>ghi</name>
</names>
```

Output needed as:

```
abc: 2
xyz: 1
def: 1
ghi: 1
```

Tried the below XPath expression :-

```
for $n in //names/name return concat($n, ': ', count(//$n))
```

But output comes like this:

```
abc: 1
abc: 1
xyz: 1
def: 1
ghi: 1
```

Comment: Is that restricted to XPath 2.0? In XQuery or XSLT you have grouping, in XPath 3.1 you could create a map with the `name` as the key.

Comment: @ManiK See another XPath 2.0 solution which is shorter and doesn't use  `concat()` or `distinct-values()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPath 3.1 would be

```
map:merge(
  /names/name!map{ string() : .}, 
  map { 'duplicates': 'combine'}) 
=> 
map:for-each(function($k, $v) {
  $k || ': ' || count($v)
})
```

In XPath 2:

```
for $distinct-name in distinct-values(/names/name)
return concat($distinct-name, ': ', count(/names/name[. = $distinct-name]))
```

Comment: Thanks Martin !! was specifically looking at XPath 2 and it works !!

Answer (score 0):

**A shorter and simpler XPath 2.0 solution** (no `distinct-values()`, no `concat()`):

```
for $v in /*/*[index-of(/*/*, .)[1]]/node()
  return ($v, ':', count(index-of(/*/*, $v)), '&#xA;')
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select=
    "for $v in /*/*[index-of(/*/*, .)[1]]/node()
      return ($v, ':', count(index-of(/*/*, $v)), '&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation   is applied on the  provided XML document**:

```
<names>
  <name>abc</name>
  <name>abc</name>
  <name>xyz</name>
  <name>def</name>
  <name>ghi</name>
</names>
```

**The XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output**:

```
abc:  2 
xyz:  1 
def:  1 
ghi:  1
```